# Segue data transfer

Tags: uistoryboardsegue, data-transfer

I tried once, but I think I did not explain myself clearly enough. Im a newbie so forgive me my lack of lingo.

I am trying to pass data from a UItextlabel's text through a modal segue to a second view controller that calculates its contents into two answers. Oh should mention it is storyboard based one!

It looks something like this:

(FirstView Controller)

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
if
    ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[SampleDelayCalculator2ViewController class]])
{
    D = d1.text;
    TT = T1.text;
    FQ = Fq1.text;

    NSLog(@"Transfering Data");

    //sending information to new view controller with a segue
    SampleDelayCalculator2ViewController *viewcontrollerB = (SampleDelayCalculator2ViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    viewcontrollerB.d.text=self.D;
    viewcontrollerB.T.text=self.TT;
    viewcontrollerB.Fq.text=self.FQ;        
}
return;
}
```

This reads straight from the UITextLabels and is performed every time button Calculate is triggered.

Then it goes to a second View

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{            
[self calculate]; 
[super viewDidLoad];
}



-(void) calculate{


//asigning the values from prepare for segue method to floats

NSLog(@"Value of string is %@", T.text);
Tf = ([T.text floatValue]);
Fqf = ([Fq.text floatValue]);
df = ([d.text floatValue]);
NSLog(@"Value of string is %f", Tf);
...
```

And then it continues to something else. 
My main problem is that whenever T.text or Tf is printed it shows nill or 0.00000 which i obviously did not put in the UITextLabel. How can I solve this problem?

I tried to implement the calculate in ViewDidAppear but that did not change anything.

I hope I made myself clear :D

Comment: if you want to know more about the code to figure this out just ask!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Be sure to give your segue a name in the storyboard.

In your first viewcontroller:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"segueToHomeDetails"]) {
        SampleDelayCalculator2ViewController *viewcontrollerB = (SampleDelayCalculator2ViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

        viewcontrollerB.d = d1.text; // don't use viewcontrollerB.d.text it won't set the text in the next controller
        viewcontrollerB.T = T1.text;
        viewcontrollerB.Fq = Fq1.text;
    }
}
```

In your 2nd viewcontroller:
Use the properties that you set up in your 2nd viewcontroller.h file.